# JavaHiveContext inssue in spark

Tags: apache-spark

I used 
spark 1.2.1
hadoop 2.3.0-cdh5.0.2
hbase 0.96.1.1-cdh5.0.2

when I run spark app, it always show the below exception.
Actually I have 
            
                org.apache.hbase
                hbase-protocol
            
And protobuf-java 2.5.0 has been build to spark assemble jar.

```
spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, cfswps1d-phys.nam.nsroot.net): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/protobuf/generated/MasterProtos$MasterService$BlockingInterface
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.createConnection(HConnectionManager.java:377)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.createConnection(HConnectionManager.java:366)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.getConnection(HConnectionManager.java:247)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:188)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:150)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat.setConf(TableInputFormat.java:101)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(NewHadoopRDD.scala:130)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.compute(NewHadoopRDD.scala:107)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.compute(NewHadoopRDD.scala:69)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:280)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:247)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MappedRDD.compute(MappedRDD.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:280)
        at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:245)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:200)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.MasterProtos$MasterService$BlockingInterface
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
        ... 23 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the classes you are referencing in your program that are mentioned in the error:  `$MasterService$BlockingInterface`  to your Spark Conf File:

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath=
```

You can read more about the extraClassPath option on the [spark site](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html).

Note: In client mode, this config must not be set through the SparkConf directly in your application, because the driver JVM has already started at that point. Instead, please set this through the --driver-class-path command line option or in your default properties file.="whatever jar file directory or class files"